# I can't apply a material to a mesh

Tags: mesh, materials

So I made a material in the image editor, I have it open, but I can't find out how to paint.
how do i apply materials to meshes?

[image]

Comment: It seems to be applied, but you don't see it as the view is in solid mode. Change to either preview or rendered (circles buttons on top right of the 3d view).

Comment: what i mean is i want to add in the texture to the left

Comment: please pack the image and share your file: https://blenderartists.org/c/support/9